# Google charts change haxis font size

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Does anyone know a way to change the font size of these dates? I want to make them a little smaller so they will all fit instead of skipping one each time..

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try with:

```
options:{
    hAxis : { 
        textStyle : {
            fontSize: 7 // or the number you want
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any document for other options ? I want to underline and change cursor to pointer.

Comment: @SunilGarg you mean change cursor in the chart canvas? You can do that with css. You want to underline the text?

Comment: Thanks @juvian. I have done this on ready event of chart
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393972/how-to-give-style-to-x-axis-of-google-charts

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue using below code:

**titleTextStyle** -- An object that specifies the title text style. The object has this format:

```
    var options = {
    title: 'Chart Name ',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
        position: "none"
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Request Status',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: "#000",
            fontName: "sans-serif",
            fontSize: 11,
            bold: true,
            italic: false
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Amount requested ($)',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: "#000",
            fontName: "sans-serif",
            fontSize: 11,
            bold: true,
            italic: false
        }
    },
    annotations: {
        alwaysOutside: true,
        textStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            auraColor: 'none'
        }
    }
};
```

[More details from Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Happy coding...

Comment: No percentage or "em" values for fontSize yet, only integer pixel values are supported at the moment in case anyone needed something else.